# JavaScript with PHP SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post

I have a problem because I can not add php session to post in javascript, or do not know how to do it, here is my code which is a problem.

```
if (!this.movesAvailable()) {
var xmlhttp = null;
  this.over = true; // Game over!
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://obiektywnywaper.pl/2048/post.php?user=&wynik="+self.score, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  alert(self.score);
}
```

I tried something like this, but it does not work

```
if (!this.movesAvailable()) {
    var xmlhttp = null;
      var user=<?echo $_SESSION['user'];?>;
      this.over = true; // Game over!
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://obiektywnywaper.pl/2048/post.php?user="+user+"&wynik="+self.score, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      alert(self.score);
    }
```

I add also the js file

```
function GameManager(size, InputManager, Actuator, ScoreManager) {
  this.size         = size; // Size of the grid
  this.inputManager = new InputManager;
  this.scoreManager = new ScoreManager;
  this.actuator     = new Actuator;

  this.startTiles   = 2;

  this.inputManager.on("move", this.move.bind(this));
  this.inputManager.on("restart", this.restart.bind(this));
  this.inputManager.on("keepPlaying", this.keepPlaying.bind(this));
  this.inputManager.on("showInfo", this.showInfo.bind(this));  
  this.inputManager.on("hideInfo", this.hideInfo.bind(this));    

  this.setup();
}

// Restart the game
GameManager.prototype.restart = function () {
  this.actuator.continue();
  this.setup();
};

// Keep playing after winning
GameManager.prototype.keepPlaying = function () {
  this.keepPlaying = true;
  this.actuator.continue();
};

GameManager.prototype.showInfo = function () {
  this.actuator.showInfo();
};


GameManager.prototype.hideInfo = function () {
  this.actuator.hideInfo();
};

GameManager.prototype.isGameTerminated = function () {
  if (this.over || (this.won && !this.keepPlaying)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

// Set up the game
GameManager.prototype.setup = function () {
  this.grid        = new Grid(this.size);

  this.score       = 0;
  this.over        = false;
  this.won         = false;
  this.keepPlaying = false;

  // Add the initial tiles
  this.addStartTiles();

  // Update the actuator
  this.actuate();
};

// Set up the initial tiles to start the game with
GameManager.prototype.addStartTiles = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.startTiles; i++) {
    this.addRandomTile();
  }
};

// Adds a tile in a random position
GameManager.prototype.addRandomTile = function () {
  if (this.grid.cellsAvailable()) {
    var value = Math.random() < 0.9 ? 2 : 4;
    var tile = new Tile(this.grid.randomAvailableCell(), value);

    this.grid.insertTile(tile);
  }
};

// Sends the updated grid to the actuator
GameManager.prototype.actuate = function () {
  if (this.scoreManager.get() < this.score) {
    this.scoreManager.set(this.score);
  }

  this.actuator.actuate(this.grid, {
    score:      this.score,
    over:       this.over,
    won:        this.won,
    bestScore:  this.scoreManager.get(),
    terminated: this.isGameTerminated()
  });

};

// Save all tile positions and remove merger info
GameManager.prototype.prepareTiles = function () {
  this.grid.eachCell(function (x, y, tile) {
    if (tile) {
      tile.mergedFrom = null;
      tile.savePosition();
    }
  });
};

// Move a tile and its representation
GameManager.prototype.moveTile = function (tile, cell) {
  this.grid.cells[tile.x][tile.y] = null;
  this.grid.cells[cell.x][cell.y] = tile;
  tile.updatePosition(cell);
};

// Move tiles on the grid in the specified direction
GameManager.prototype.move = function (direction) {
  // 0: up, 1: right, 2:down, 3: left
  var self = this;

  if (this.isGameTerminated()) return; // Don't do anything if the game's over

  var cell, tile;

  var vector     = this.getVector(direction);
  var traversals = this.buildTraversals(vector);
  var moved      = false;

  // Save the current tile positions and remove merger information
  this.prepareTiles();

  // Traverse the grid in the right direction and move tiles
  traversals.x.forEach(function (x) {
    traversals.y.forEach(function (y) {
      cell = { x: x, y: y };
      tile = self.grid.cellContent(cell);

      if (tile) {
        var positions = self.findFarthestPosition(cell, vector);
        var next      = self.grid.cellContent(positions.next);

        // Only one merger per row traversal?
        if (next && next.value === tile.value && !next.mergedFrom) {
          var merged = new Tile(positions.next, tile.value * 2);
          merged.mergedFrom = [tile, next];

          self.grid.insertTile(merged);
          self.grid.removeTile(tile);

          // Converge the two tiles' positions
          tile.updatePosition(positions.next);

          // Update the score
          self.score += merged.value;

          // The mighty 2048 tile
          if (merged.value === 2048) self.won = true;
        } else {
          self.moveTile(tile, positions.farthest);
        }

        if (!self.positionsEqual(cell, tile)) {
          moved = true; // The tile moved from its original cell!
        }
      }
    });
  });

  if (moved) {
    this.addRandomTile();

    if (!this.movesAvailable()) {
    var xmlhttp = null;
      this.over = true; // Game over!
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://obiektywnywaper.pl/2048/post.php?user=&wynik="+self.score, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      alert(self.score);
    }

    this.actuate();
  }
};

// Get the vector representing the chosen direction
GameManager.prototype.getVector = function (direction) {
  // Vectors representing tile movement
  var map = {
    0: { x: 0,  y: -1 }, // up
    1: { x: 1,  y: 0 },  // right
    2: { x: 0,  y: 1 },  // down
    3: { x: -1, y: 0 }   // left
  };

  return map[direction];
};

// Build a list of positions to traverse in the right order
GameManager.prototype.buildTraversals = function (vector) {
  var traversals = { x: [], y: [] };

  for (var pos = 0; pos < this.size; pos++) {
    traversals.x.push(pos);
    traversals.y.push(pos);
  }

  // Always traverse from the farthest cell in the chosen direction
  if (vector.x === 1) traversals.x = traversals.x.reverse();
  if (vector.y === 1) traversals.y = traversals.y.reverse();

  return traversals;
};

GameManager.prototype.findFarthestPosition = function (cell, vector) {
  var previous;

  // Progress towards the vector direction until an obstacle is found
  do {
    previous = cell;
    cell     = { x: previous.x + vector.x, y: previous.y + vector.y };
  } while (this.grid.withinBounds(cell) &&
           this.grid.cellAvailable(cell));

  return {
    farthest: previous,
    next: cell // Used to check if a merge is required
  };
};

GameManager.prototype.movesAvailable = function () {
  return this.grid.cellsAvailable() || this.tileMatchesAvailable();
};

// Check for available matches between tiles (more expensive check)
GameManager.prototype.tileMatchesAvailable = function () {
  var self = this;

  var tile;

  for (var x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
      tile = this.grid.cellContent({ x: x, y: y });

      if (tile) {
        for (var direction = 0; direction < 4; direction++) {
          var vector = self.getVector(direction);
          var cell   = { x: x + vector.x, y: y + vector.y };

          var other  = self.grid.cellContent(cell);

          if (other && other.value === tile.value) {
            return true; // These two tiles can be merged
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}; 


GameManager.prototype.positionsEqual = function (first, second) {
  return first.x === second.x && first.y === second.y;
};
```

Comment: Not really necessary to print a session var into JS and send it back to the server, since its already on the server in the session. In fact, doing this can create a security flaw.

Comment: That's how I can solve this? You can give an example?

Comment: In other words, in your PHP file being called by the Ajax retrieve the user from the session not from the GET params....because its already in the session and the data in the session is more trustworthy.  Uses can manipulate the GET params...

Comment: I do not know how to do it, I'm probably too stupid ...

Comment: In other words, wherever post.php has `$_GET['user']` just change that to `$_SESSION['user']` and don't worry about transmitting the user back and forth between session and javascript.

Comment: Ok, but on my post.php I get some like this "UPDATE  `krytykak_inawera`.`2048` SET  `score` =  '1396' WHERE  `2048`.`user` = '' " my $name = $_SESSION['user']; is empty, where is my SESSION ?:(

Comment: Either you didn't call `session_start()` at the top of the page, or you did, but you never put anything in the session, which means it will be empty.

Comment: I put to session in functions.php in file game.php i See my session, on the post.php i put session_start(); in the top but still not working

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me, but I was a little overwhelmed. Now it's working, I still had one error in the file post.php

Answer (score 1):

I don't know php, but classic asp works in similar fashion as far as I know. If you set the variable outside the scope of the function, and also include apostrophes, it should work.

```
var user="<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>"; //possibly declared outside of scope
```

Edited as per @developerwjk's comment about the php-syntax

Comment: As I said I don't know the php syntax. In classic asp it would be var x='<%=Session("user")%>';. Since the session is set on server, javascript would just see the value as any other string value, not the actual asp call.

Comment: Actually there is a slight syntax error. Should be at least a space after `<?` and for older servers better to use `<?php` than `<?` so: `var user="<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>";`